# Qual a maneira correta de passar dois ou mais parâmetros na rota?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Estou tentando passar dois parâmetros na rota, porém, recebo este erro:

> "Route pattern "/ficha/{id}/cliente/{id}" cannot reference variable name "id" more than once."

A rota utilizada:

```
Route::get('/visualizar/{ficha_id}/{cliente_id}', 'AnamneseController@visualizar')
->name('visualizar');
```

Botão onde é passado o parâmetro:

```
<a href="{{route('ficha.visualizar', ['ficha_id' => $f->id, 'cliente_id' => $cliente->id])}}">
    Visualizar Ficha
</a>
```

Estou fazendo algo de errado? O que devo corrigir?

*EDIT*
Todas as rotas da aplicação

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['as' => 'cadastro.', 'prefix' => 'cadastro'], function () {
    Route::get('/listar', 'CadastroController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/adicionar', 'CadastroController@create')->name('adicionar');
    Route::post('/salvar', 'CadastroController@store')->name('salvar');
    Route::get('/{id}/visualizar', 'CadastroController@show')->name('visualizar');
    Route::get('/{id}/editar', 'CadastroController@edit')->name('editar');
});

Route::group(['as' => 'ficha.', 'prefix' => 'ficha'], function () {
    Route::get('/listar', 'AnamneseController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/cliente/{id}/adicionar', 'AnamneseController@create')->name('adicionar');
    Route::get('/{id}/cliente/{id}', 'AnamneseController@edit')->name('editar');
    Route::post('/salvar', 'AnamneseController@store')->name('salvar');
    Route::get('/visualizar/{ficha_id}/{cliente_id}', 'AnamneseController@visualizar')->name('visualizar');
});
```

Comment: Tente trocar `ficha_id` por `fichaId` e ver o que acontece.

Comment: Você postou a rota certa? O erro diz respeito a rota `"/ficha/{id}/cliente/{id}"`  e você postou uma rota `'/visualizar/{ficha_id}/{cliente_id}'`.

Comment: @LINQ troquei e não mudou nada...

Comment: @AndreGusmao sim, a rota está correta. Porém, não importa o nome que eu coloque entre " `{ }` " permanece `/ficha/{id}/cliente/{id}`

Comment: Tem como colocar todas as suas rotas acho que tem rotas com problemas?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei e inseri todas as rotas.

Comment: `Route::get('/{id}/cliente/{id}', 'AnamneseController@edit')->name('editar');` não pode ser assim! uns dos erros é esse ele só aceita um nome de variavel por rota

Comment: Poxa vida, estava cego querendo resolver o problema da rota visualizar que nem me atentei a verificar as outras.. Resolveu aqui... @VirgilioNovic, muuuito obrigado, cara!

Answer (score 1):

Meu amigo, o proprio erro ja diz "cannot reference variable name "id" more than once.". Tu nao pode referenciar o nome da variavel "id" mais de uma vez!

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{id}/cliente/{id}', 'AnamneseController@edit')->name('editar');
```

Você tem que mudar essa parte, não pode ter 2 ids, coloca {id} e {cliente}, por exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Só pra deixar uma opção, caso já tenha resolvido.

Estava com o mesmo problema e resolvi passando um array junto com a rota associando cada valor com o respectivo id.

Ex. `('nome_da_rota',array('fichaID'=>$ficha_id, 'clienteID'=>$cliente_id))`

Achei [nesse post](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-problema-com-redirect-action-com-parametro-19700).